# Не добавляются комментарии(python-django) на сайте

Tags: python, django, комментарии

Помогите пожалуйста с проблемой! У меня есть ссылка `leave_comment`,отвечающая за добавления комментов на сайте, так-же создал вьюшку `leave_comment`, в общем я решил поменять название этой ссылки, потом хотел вернуть обратно (до того как поменял название все добавлялось), вернул старое название ссылки и комменты не добавляются,я просто ввожу текст в поле ввода, жму и ничего не происходит,текст так же остается в поле ввода и никуда не исчезает! Вот код `urls.py` приложения:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views 

app_name = 'articles'

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
        path('<int:article_id>/', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
        path('<int:article_id>/leave_comment/', views.leave_comment, name = 'leave_comment')
    ]
```

Вот код `views.py` (тоже приложение):

```
from django.http import Http404,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render 

from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Article, Comment

def index(request):
    test = Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    return render(request,'articles/list.html',{'test':test})

def detail(request,article_id):
    try:    
        a = Article.objects.get(id = article_id)      
    except:
        raise Http404('Статьи не найдены')    

    test2 = a.comment_set.order_by('-id')[:10]

    return render(request,'articles/detail.html',{'article': a, 'test2': test2})

def leave_comment(request,article_id):
    try:    
        a = Article.objects.get(id = article_id)      
    except:
        raise Http404('Статьи не найдены')
    a.comment_set.create(author_name = request.POST['name'],comment_text = request.POST['text'])    

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('articles:detail', args = (a.id,)) )
```

И вот `detail.py` (лежит в папке проекта `Мой проект/templates/articles articles` - мое приложение) потому что изменял название этой ссылки только в 3 файлах:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{article.article_title}}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>{{article.article_title}}</h1>

<h2>{{article.article_text}}</h2>

<em>{{article.pub_date}}</em> 
<hr>

{% if test2 %}
    {% for c in test2  %}
    <p>
        <strong>{{c.author_name}}</strong>
        <p>{{c.comment_text}}</p>
    {% endfor  %}    
    </p>
{% else %}
Комментарии не найдены!    
{% endif %}

<hr>

<form action="{% url 'articles:leave_comment' article.id %}" method="POST"></form>

    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type = 'text' required placeholder="Введите имя", name = 'name'><br>
    <textarea name="text" required placeholder="Текст комментария" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
    <button type = 'submit'>Добавить комментарий</button>
</form>
```

Comment: у тебя <form> открывается и тут же закрывается, в итоге поле для ввода и кнопки вне формы находятся

Comment: Пасиба за ответ) Спустя год :)